# Many-to-many relation with attributes in refClass

Tags: model, symfony1, doctrine, data-modeling, orm

I'm currently designing a website, using symfony (1.2) with Doctrine as an ORM.

I have a Dinner class, a Criteria class, and a Mark class.

- A Mark is linked with a Dinner and a
  Criteria, and has private attributes,
  like DateOfMark, MarkValue, etc.
- Dinner and Criteria can have many
  Marks (or none).

As I use Doctrine, I define this model in my schema.yml, using the following code :

```
Dinner:
  columns:
    date: { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
    nb_presents: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Marks:
      class:    Criteria
      local:    dinner_id
      foreign:  criteria_id
      refClass: Mark

Criteria:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(50), notnull: true }
  relation:
    Marks:
      class:    Dinner
      local:    criteria_id
      foreign:  dinner_id
      refClass: Mark

Mark:
  columns:
    criteria_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    dinner_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    value: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Dinner:
      local:    dinner_id
      foreign:  id
    Criteria:
      local:    criteria_id
      foreign:  id
```

Problem is that the SQL generated by Doctrine, it adds a  `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` on `Mark.dinner_id` to `Dinner.id` (which is correct) **AND** it adds a `FOREIGN KEY CONSTRAINT` on `Dinner.id` to `Mark.dinner_id` (which is really incorrect, as a Dinner might have many Marks).

### Question

Did I miss something ? Am I doing this kind of relation between classes wrong ?

Thanks you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to define the relation as being a one-to-many relation. Try this (note the "type: many" added to the Dinner and Criteria definitions):

```
Dinner:
  columns:
    date: { type: timestamp, notnull: true }
    nb_presents: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Marks:
      class:    Criteria
      local:    dinner_id
      foreign:  criteria_id
      refClass: Mark
      type: many

Criteria:
  columns:
    name: { type: string(50), notnull: true }
 relation:
   Marks:
     class:    Dinner
     local:    criteria_id
     foreign:  dinner_id
     refClass: Mark
     type: many

Mark:
  columns:
    criteria_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    dinner_id: { type: integer, primary: true }
    value: { type: integer, notnull: true }
  relations:
    Dinner:
      local:    dinner_id
      foreign:  id
    Criteria:
      local:    criteria_id
      foreign:  id
```